# Angular 6+ - Should/must an object made of behavior subjects, be a behavior subject itself?

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I am working on a project, where I use several  **behavior subjects** in the same service, to keep track of several objects **having influence on each other and coming from different parts of the application** :

- current items collected (list)
- current points calculated from the collected items
- current level calculated from the points, 
  etc

Now, I would like to **gather all these in a new object** called 'user statistics', to be able to display them altogether on a dedicated page, and it would feel logical to make it a **new behavior subject made of all the previous behavior subjects**, but it also feels kind of redundant/hacky,

But is there another possibility anyway ?
What would be the best way to proceed here ?

Any thought on that would be welcome : )

Comment: Why not just use an rxjs map? You could also combine them with other rxjs operators such as `combineLatest`.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all behaviorsuject into one Observable.zip method, then you can collect all latest values of each behaviourSubject values.
See the Example

**Observable.zip(behaviorSubject1, behaviorSubject2, behaviorSubject3...).subscribe((resp: any) => {
 console.log(resp);
});**

the resp will be map with each behaviorSubject key and values.
Note: Don't use **Observable.combineLatest** as which will not return closer value of behaviorSubject.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I didn't know this zip operator, sounds about perfect for the case : )

Comment: Most welcome and let me know in case of any issues. If you have any freelance project, please let me know. I am eager to work on it.

Comment: --- will do ; )